# Mongo $pullAll on array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Currently I have a data structure like this in mongo:

```
{
    "_id": "field00048",
    "colorValues": [
        {
            "stateField": "Open1",
            "color": "purple"
        },
        {
            "stateField": "Open2",
            "color": "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the mongo shell to create a query using $pullAll to delete both of the objects in the colorValues array by matching on the stateField field. I have tried these queries but none of them actually delete the records they match on.

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {stateField: ["Open1", "Open2"]}});
```

and

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {colorValues: ["Open1", "Open2"]}});
```

and

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {colorValues: [{stateField:"Open1"}, {stateField:"Open2"}]}});
```

and

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {colorValues.stateField: ["Open1", "Open2"]}});
```

and

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {colorValues: stateField:{["Open1", "Open2"]}}});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `$pullAll` takes the list of values to be deleted and `$pull` takes filter. Something like `db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pull: {colorValues:{stateField:{$in: ["Open1", "Open2"]}}}})`; or `db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pullAll: {"colorValues.stateField":["Open1", "Open2"]}})`

Comment: I just tried those queries and it still didn't delete @Veeram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb pull all element from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598685/mongodb-pull-all-element-from-the-array)

Answer (score 12):

The query that solved this was:

```
db.admin.fields.update({_id: "field00048"}, {$pull: {colorValues:{stateField:{$in: ["Open1", "Open2"]}}}})
```